# Open CV Frame does not show up for Laptop camera

Tags: opencv

I am trying to do face detection in Open CV , however when i run my code i see camera light in laptop on , but the frame does not show up on system .

Can anyone help ?

below is the code

print("[INFO] loading model .....")

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"],args["model"])

## initialize video stream

print("[INFO] starting video stream ....")

vs =VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(1.0)

while True:

```
frame = vs.read()
frame =imutils.resize(frame,width=400)
(h,w)=frame.shape[:2]


blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame,(300,300)),1.0,(300,300),(104.0,177.0,123.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing src=1 instead of src=0

```
vs =VideoStream(src=1).start() time.sleep(1.0)
```